# LINQ after looping over and modifying items in enumerable filtered with .Where(), items disappear - why?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

While bug-fixing some code, I ran into some unexpected behavior where it seemed like items were disappearing from an IEnumerable after looping over it.

I'm trying to understand why this is happening and I wrote up a small test project to test out this behavior.

To briefly explain the code below,

1. I have a class (TestObject) that has a single property - an int
2. I create a List of TestObject and add 5 new TestObjects to it, all with the int property == 5
3. I "filter" the list with LINQ's .Where() function, only getting the TestObjects where the int == 5
   (every element in the list)
4. I loop over the elements of the IEnumerable, setting the int property to 0 for each element
5. The IEnumerable is now empty

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestingGroundProject
{
    class TestObject
    {
        public TestObject(int intVal)
        {
            IntVal = intVal;
        }

        public int IntVal { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TestObject> testList = new();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                testList.Add(new TestObject(5));

            //this line results in expected behavior 
            //(5 elements in testEnum, all IntVal's are 0 after the loop)
            //var testEnum = testList.AsEnumerable();

            //this line results in unexpected behavior 
            //(0 elements in testEnum after the loop)
            var testEnum = testList.Where(t => t.IntVal == 5);

            //prints "5"
            Console.WriteLine(testEnum.Count());

            foreach (var t in testEnum)
                t.IntVal = 0;

            //prints "0"
            Console.WriteLine(testEnum.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with a yield return that's being done in the background inside of .Where() that grabs the next element in the enumerable that matches the predicate, and I'm interfering with that by altering the elements of the enumerable while iterating over it, but could someone confirm/explain this?

(I did try to look up any documentation on the .Where() function's behavior at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0), but it didn't really answer my question.)

Is this also why .AsEnumerable() doesn't seem to have this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is because LINQ is lazy until you call `Count`. It starts filtering only after this call. So you have changed elements and filter omitted previous values. If you want stability, just call ToList() - `var testEnum = testList.Where(t => t.IntVal == 5).ToList();`

Comment: If you call Where the only thing that’s done is that a new class implementing IEnumerable is returned which will return the items satisfying the given predicate ONCE the enumerable is enumerated. This behavior is documented at your link in the remarks section.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv For my clarity, are you saying that the second `Count` is filtering the list a second time?

Comment: Yes, only `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc. runs filter immediately and stores result in collection.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you very much. If you leave an answer, I'll accept yours since you beat the other guy by about 2 minutes. @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Don't worry accept first answer, it is correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEnumerable is not executed until you invoke something which requires iteration, like your Count(). So the two times you call Count() the sequence will be calculated separately. This is the reason for the items disappearing the second time. If you wish to keep the sequence at a given point you could invoke ToList() and keep it in a variable.